# Unable to get WebView Context

Tags: ios, webview, appium, wdio

I'm currently working on automating IOS App using Appium and sauce labs with webdriverio. App has a login screen coming in a web view. But when I use driver.getContexts() its returning only 1 entry i.e, NATIVE_APP.

I have added capabilities like, fullContextsList, IncludeSafariInWebviews but It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you have already tried setting IncludeSafariInWebviews as true, Please try one more capability `appium:webviewConnectTimeout` and set its value as `9000`. This will wait for presense of webview in safari or any hybrid app

Comment: I tried both capabilities and used the wait-until function in wdio. It worked for a while. but now with a new build, It's not working again

Comment: what is error message you are getting? is it giving you same error something like "No webview present"

Comment: Yes... When I print the context array, It's only containing [ 'NATIVE_APP' ].

Comment: Can you try doing this using Appium Inspector before doing through script. I observed that some time WebView take way longer to be appeared and get identified even though available.  
Also you can try reinstalling below packages  
`brew uninstall ios-webkit-debug-proxy && brew install ios-webkit-debug-proxy --HEAD`  
`brew uninstall libusbmuxd && brew install libusbmuxd --HEAD`  
`brew uninstall libimobiledevice && brew install libimobiledevice --HEAD`

Comment: Thanks for the response Monil :-). But I'm carrying out my testing using Windows Machine and sauce labs devices.

Comment: Hi All, This issue is happening because of new changes included in iOS 16. access to web inspector is disabled by default